# Why the output of seekp and write is so strange?

Tags: c++, file, file-io

The code is listed below

```
fstream file("1.txt", ios::out);
if (!file){
    cout << "Error opening file.";
    return 0;
}
file.seekp(5L, ios::beg);
file.write(";;;\0", 20);

file.seekp(-10L, ios::end);
file.write(";;\0", 20);

file.seekp(0, ios::cur);
file.write(";\0", 20);
```

Here is the ouput for the code(in "1.txt")

```
"     ;;;     ;;;;  ;   front() call;   front() called o"
```

What's wrong with the code such that there are some many ';'?

I think 6 ';' is expected. And after the ';'  what is the "front() call;...." come from?

Comment: can you maybe try writing something that allows you to see exactly what wrote which character, when? This would be trivial to answer if you didn't write a lot of `;`, but instead of `;;;\0` wrote `abcd`, instead of `;;\0` wrote `efg`, instead of `;\0` wrote `hi`.

Comment: also, what do you *think* the `20` in your `write` calls is for?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but writing to a file should usually be done with `std::ofstream file("1.txt");`, that is, an **output** stream. There's hardly ever a need for the generality of `std::fstream`.

Comment: i hope you are not writing code by guessing but have some idea of what the contents of the file should be. If so, it would help if you include that in the question. In other words "Whats wrong with the code?" its not doing what you expect it to do. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Also, writing to a file opened in text mode, you better know beforehand what to expect.  Text mode has that translation thing going on, and you need to be prepared to figure out what is outputted when and where if you're going to use `seekp`.  This is why choosing `;;;` and `;;` to test your code is a very poor choice of text to be using as test data,

Comment: this page should answer your questions. all of them. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write